# Question about Continuous Functions

Tags: real-analysis

I do not know how to draw here so i will write the equation.

let say we have

$$y= -x-3,\,x\leq 0$$ 
    $$y = x +3,\,x\geq 0$$

can you say this function is continuous?

or how about

$$y= -x-3,\,x\leq 0$$ 
    $$y = x +3,\,x >0$$

1. and the function should be continuous for derivative.
   but every continuous function derivitive?

Im try to answer this question with above assumption.

Comment: Hint: do the two parts agree on the boundary?

Answer (score 0):

We know that it will be continuous for $x > 0$, as $y = x + 3$ is continuous. We also know that it will be continuous for $x < 0$, as $y = -x - 3$ is continuous.

The only point that we may be unsure of is at $x = 0$, because this is where a transition occurs. However, if the functions have the same value at this point, then that point will be continuous between the two functions, and there would remain no more potential points for discontinuity.

Let's check:

$$(0)+3=3$$
$$-(0)-3=-3$$

Two different values at $x = 0$. Thus, the function is not continuous.

Comment: and the function should be continuous for derivative. but every continuous function derivitive?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: for derivative condition. function must be continuous. but every continuous function is derivatable? for every point of the function

Comment: Yes; if the function is differentiable at a point, it must be continuous at that point.

Comment: and continuous guarantee the derivatiality?

Comment: No. A function can be continuous but not differentiable.